# How to calculate weight vector w in SVM and what does it mean by the vectors?

Tags: svm

What is interpretation of the weight vector in SVM. I searched a lot but did not find any relevant document. Could anyone explain please?

Comment: Why are you looking; what is the purpose?  Where have you searched?  Why did what you found in your search not speak to you?  What do you wish you had in the way of a source?  Are you looking for published articles, or tutorials and lecture material?